# How to include Typescript types for Google cloud storage in firebase cloud functions

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a Firebase cloud function written in Typescript where I access a Google storage bucket.

If I get the bucket like this:

```
const storageBucket = admin.storage().bucket(storageBucketName);
```

VScode shows storageBucket has the type Bucket.

But if I try to use this as parameter on a function:

```
async function deleteOldBackup(storageBucket: Bucket) {
```

the type Bucket is underline in red as "cannot find Bucket".

If I try to import the Bucket type like this:

```
import { Bucket, File } from "@google-cloud/storage"
```

I get the error that Bucket from admin is different than the Bucket in my deleteOldBackup functions.

How can I get propper Typescript type for google storage in my firebase cloud functions?

Answer (score 2):

Update dependencies to the latest versions and it'll work.

I've got these and the types are matching:

```
"dependencies": {
  "firebase-admin": "^9.3.0",
  "firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
  "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.4.0"
}
```

Comment: Even tho this works we need to reference the types. So they should be exported somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The way that you have to import the Client Library is like this line:“const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');”

If you want, for example, list the objects in your bucket. You have to use something like this code:

/

```
**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following line before running the sample.
 */
// const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function listFiles() {
  // Lists files in the bucket
  const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();

  console.log('Files:');
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file.name);
  });
}

listFiles().catch(console.error);
```

You can find more information about this example in the [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-bucket-information#storage-get-bucket-metadata-nodejs) and more information about the client library in the [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs).

Answer (score 0):

Hm ... this works for me now:

```
import { File } from "@google-cloud/storage";

type GetFileHelperResult = {
  file?: File;
};
```

I'm using:

```
"firebase": "8.2.6",
"firebase-admin": "^9.2.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.11.0",
```